# Trigger a function upon Weblogic termination

Tags: java, weblogic

Is there anyway to capture weblogic termination event and trigger a Java function?

My weblogic version is V10.0

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could imlement a `javax.servlet.ServletContextListener`

```
public class MyServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
  public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent e) {
  }

  public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent e) {
  }
}
```

and add it to the web.xml.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>MyServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

There you can handle the shutdwn of the weblogic container.